# INSERT trigger from another table from a linked Server is slow

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert, linked-server

I have three tables:

`(table_a)` has an AFTER INSERT trigger that inserts rows from another table `(table_b)` from a linked server into a local table `(table_c)`.

Whenever a lot number is inserted into `(table_a)`, the trigger inserts from `(table_b)` into `(table_c)` rows that contain the same column value as the lot number.

This seems to slow, sometimes freeze operations on my server. I found that insert from a table from a local server seems to run fine, so I suspect the problem is caused because it inserts from a linked server.

How can I improve insert speed?

Comment: @DaleK do you mean the trigger should queue perhaps a stored procedure, then have the stored procedure carry out the actual insert action?

Comment: @DaleK thank you for the replies, I will try to solve the issue with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers should always be written to be as fast as possible to avoid exactly this problem. Intensive operations of any kind should ideally not be carried out within a trigger. That applies doubly when the operation involves contacting other servers as that can easily end up taking real time.

Instead queue the action and process your queue outside the trigger using a service or agent.

A queue might looks like a record in a table which gets flagged once processed. The record needs to contain enough information for the service to carry out the related actions, which could be contained within a Stored Procedure.